# Replication 2008 publisher to 2008r2 subscriber

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, database-replication

Is there a way that the replication mechanism can handle such the topology, where SQL SRV 2008 is a publisher and will provide publication to 2008 r2 subscriber?

Thank You in an advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this topology will work with Transactional Replication.  It will not work with Merge Replication.

Per [Using Multiple Versions of SQL Server in a Replication Topology](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143241%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> For all types of replication, the Distributor version must be no
>   earlier than the Publisher version. (Frequently, the Distributor is
>   the same instance as the Publisher.)
>
> For transactional replication, a Subscriber to a transactional
>   publication can be any version within two versions of the Publisher
>   version. For example, a SQL Server 2000 Publisher can have SQL Server
>   2008 Subscribers, and a SQL Server 2008 Publisher can have SQL Server
>   2000 Subscribers.
>
> For merge replication, a Subscriber to a merge publication can be any
>   version no later than the Publisher version. For more information
>   about compatibility for earlier versions, see "Compatibility Level for
>   Merge Publications" later in this topic. For more information about
>   replication features that are supported in the various editions of SQL
>   Server, see Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2008 R2.